# Clean k8s cronjob and its running pods

Tags: cron, kubernetes

I encountered one weird  cleanup issue in k8s when cleaning up CronJob and its associated running Pods. Look like some component created a new Pod when i did the following:

1. Delete the CronJob by using REST API of k8s
2. Delete the Pod by using REST API of k8s

What I expected after doing 1) and then 2), there will be no CronJob Pod will be running. But i observed:

1. The CronJob has been deleted
2. The existing running Pods are deleted also
3. A new CronJob Pod is created by some component in k8s

I am wondering if the steps to clean up CronJob and its Pods is correct and which component in k8s creates the new CronJob Pod ?

Comment: To see how a job cleanup can be done by using k8s APIs, the best thing to do is to use kubectl --v=8 delete job <job-name> and monitoring. kubectl will first fetch the running pods for a job and delete them. Once they are deleted, kubectl will deleted the job. Cleanups are a little weird to understand in k8s for the first time.

Comment: Do you observe the new pods that every time or is it flaky? If it's flaky, it could be a race in the cronjob controller, which is expected. kubectl uses the scale interface to scale down the job, then delete the remaining pods, and finally deletes the job. See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.6.0-alpha.0/pkg/kubectl/stop.go#L372.

Comment: Observe the new pods almost every time. May i ask if there is any replica set behind a cronjob ?